# How to use ReadPrinter?

Tags: delphi

I am sending prints directly to the spool like this:

```
var
 cmnd : TBytes;
 ...   
 WritePrinter(HandleImp, @cmnd[0], Length(cmnd), CaracteresImpressos);
 ...
```

In most cases, this satisfies my need, my problem is about commands that require a printer response, Read status for example.

I read about the function `ReadPrinter ()`, but I can not use it...the return is always different from 0 (according to the documentation indicating that the function was performed), but the buffer comes empty, as if the printer does not respond.

The return of "ci" equals 0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/printdocs/readprinter

This is the my code:

```
function TTP650.pedeStatusDrawer: TBytes;
    begin
      SetLength(result, 3);
      result[0] := 16;
      result[1] := 04;
      result[2] := 01;
    end;

function TForm1.statusDrawer: boolean;
    var
      buffer : TBytes;
      cmnd : TBytes;
      s : string;
      i : integer;
      ret : boolean;
      ci: DWORD;
    begin
      setLength(buffer,20);
      DescricaoAnsiString := 'Lendo Pulso/Gaveta' + #10;
      cmnd := tp.pedeStatusDrawer();

      if not OpenPrinter(PChar(driverselecionado), HandleImp, nil) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Erro: Impressora não encontrada')
      else
      begin

      Documento.pDocName := PChar('Minha impressão');
      Documento.pOutputFile := nil;
      Documento.pDataType := 'RAW';

      StartDocPrinter(HandleImp, 1, @Documento);
      StartPagePrinter(HandleImp);

      WritePrinter(HandleImp, @cmnd[0], Length(cmnd), CaracteresImpressos);
      ret := ReadPrinter(HandleImp, @buffer[0], Length(buffer), ci);

      EndPagePrinter(HandleImp);
      EndDocPrinter(HandleImp);

      if(ret = true) then
      begin
          if(ci >0) then
          begin
            for i := 0 to Length(buffer)-1 do
            s := s + IntToStr(buffer[i]) + ' ';

            Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
          end;

      end;
      ClosePrinter(HandleImp);
      end;

    end;
```

I'm working with a bi-directional thermal printer.
Excerpt from the documentation:

```
[Name] Real-time status transmission 

[Format] ASCII   DLE  EOT n 

          Hex     10  04  n 

          Decimal 16  4   n

[Description]
```

Transmits the selected printer status specified by n in real-time, according to the following parameters:

```
n = 1: Transmit printer status 

n = 2: Transmit offline status 

n = 3: Transmit error status 

n = 4: Transmit paper roll sensor status
```

If there is interest, full documentation (pages 9 and 10 discuss the subject).
[printer documentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kkw9LQYPA8G7P50Vvp7elMbiximDDAUN/view)

Comment: You've allocated no space in `teste`, and the call to `Length(teste)` returns zero. How do you expect that to work when you pass it a zero-length buffer to fill? You also do not test the return value of the function before using the results with `Memo1.Lines.Add(teste)`, which clearly will fail both with an empty string and if the function fails because there is no data to read or the printer is not bi-directional.

Comment: @KenWhite I made the changes as suggested, but always returns 0. The printer is bidirectional, I have codes in other languages that work. What other points can I evaluate?

Comment: `Length(Buffer)` is wrong. Static arrays don't have `Length`. Use `SizeOf` instead. You should really learn the language and how to use the debugger. :-)

Comment: Also, just because the printer is bidirectional, that doesn't mean that it sends information after every operation. What makes you think that it does in response to the specific WritePrinter calls you're making?

Comment: @KenWhite I have another code that works ... I send the command and the printer responds. The difference between them is that one sends uniqueness to the port (ex: COM3) and the other sends to the driver and spool.

Comment: Winner, 2019 Most Improved Question Evar. I'd answer but I got no idea at all. Delphi and thermal printers, eew. Good luck.

Comment: Buffer is only 20 bytes. Is that large enough?

Comment: @GolezTrol According to the manual yes ... but I used 100 bytes to be sure, it did not work.Can you tell if the ReadPrinter is in the correct position?

Comment: @KenWhite: Static arrays most definitely have a `Length`, and that returns the number of **elements** they can contain. `SizeOf` returns the number of **bytes**. Since we are talking about `TBytes` (which is now dynamic), they should both return the same value.

Comment: @Rudy: Yep. I'd forgotten that static arrays have the pretty much useless property Length. It's mostly meaningless, because (since they're static) you can't change the length, and as they don't always start at a known index of 0 it's more frequent to use `Low` and `High` instead. Yes, in this case they happen to return the same value, but it wouldn't be the case if the array was of any other type such as `Char` or `Double` or `Integer`, and using `SizeOf` is what the API function is expecting.

Comment: @Ken: no, it is not meaningless at all. It gives you the number of elements (say, Chars or Integers) you can store in it. That is useful, IMO. And not every API function expects a SizeOf value either. Take a look at, say, GetWindowTextW. This expects the number of (16 bit) characters the buffer can contain (i.e. the Length) and **not the size in bytes** (SizeOf) .

Comment: @Rudy: Ok. You win. In a single instance, you're right. `GetWindowText` does expect the value in chars. The vast majority of WinAPI functions do not, however, and as a general rule `SizeOf` is the correct value to pass. Of course, you know this already, but for some reason want to add clutter here about `GetWindowTextW` being an exception. You win. It's an exception to the general rule. Again, you win.

Comment: @Ken: I'm sure I could find a lot more. Anything that expects an **array** of values (points, etc.)and not just a raw buffer will use the number of elements, not the buffer size. As I said, Length is not useless, not on dynamic and not on static arrays. Can be that you don't need it a lot, but that is just anecdotal.

Comment: Has any progress been made on this issue?

Comment: Perhaps checking the return of all those API functions tells you what exactly fails. `StartDocPrinter()` returns a `DWORD` print job id or zero if fails. All others return `BOOL`. You never said what value you have in `ci` after `ReadPrinter()`. All this information is normal debugging information. Why did you not include it in your question?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg The print functions (StartDocPrinter() ) are working, if I send any command to be printer works. The return of "ci" equals 0.

Comment: If `ReadPrinter()` and everything else before, returns without error and `ci` is 0, then your printer is broken or not setup properly. Maybe your exact model doesn't support this command? Oh dear, good luck.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg The printer is working and configured correctly. I have another code, using serial communication (Synaser -> TBlockSerial) that works.

Comment: Sorry, but as I don't have such a printer, I can't help you further. Double check the docs, just in case ...

Comment: @Tom Brunberg this code that I have, does it work with the printer you have?

Comment: I don't expect it to. I have a HP-1600, uses PCL5, looks different from your printers language.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg I think my error is not in the printer language, but in some detail of delphi I did not notice ... if you could use your language, assigning a "cmnd" status reading command, for example, to test the rest ... would be grateful.

Comment: I think the problem is that Windows does not allow reading from a printer handle.
However it should be possible to read from a print *job* handle.

There is a discussion about this on Google Groups, with [example code provided by Jeffrey Tan](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/C-uBnDGfwOo/G0lDqm5zKq0J).

Having said that, I tried a quick test with sending PJL commands to an HP Laserjet printer and it did not quite work as required: ReadPrinter() returned the command I sent to the printer, rather than the response from the printer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer using serial communication.
I made the send commands of the strings I mentioned in the question via serial and read:

```
Serial: TBlockSerial;
b: = Serial.RecvByte (500);
```

It worked.